# Exception throws on contextmenu item selection in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, contextmenu

UserIndex:

```
  @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.users_index);
            listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
            getdata();
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                          int position, long id) {
                      TextView uname=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.sendername);
                          username = uname.getText().toString();
                          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                          i.putExtra("username", username);
                          startActivity(i);
                      }
                    });
        }


    private void getdata() {
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("/data/data/net.multiplesystem.nosms/Messeges/UserList.xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("details");

            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;

                    String a=eElement.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).getTextContent().toString();
                    userIndex.add(a);
            }
           }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    setListAdapter();
}

private void setListAdapter(){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.user_index_layout,R.id.sendername,userIndex);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
}
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
     if (v.getId()==R.id.listview) {
         MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
     }
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    String userdetail=((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
        try {
            File fXmlFile = new File("/data/data/net.multiplesystem.nosms/Messeges/"+userdetail+".xml");
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
            if(fXmlFile.exists()){
                fXmlFile.delete();
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(info.position));
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

user_index_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sendername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/duration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/sendername"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
02-20 03:17:59.623: E/AndroidRuntime(3561): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 03:17:59.623: E/AndroidRuntime(3561): Process: net.multiplesystem.nosms, PID: 3561
02-20 03:17:59.623: E/AndroidRuntime(3561): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
02-20 03:17:59.623: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at net.multiplesystem.nosms.messegebox.UserIndex.onContextItemSelected(UserIndex.java:153)
02-20 03:17:59.623: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2619)
02-20 03:17:59.623: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DialogMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:3808)
02-20 03:17:59.623: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
02-20 03:17:59.623: E/AndroidRuntime(3561):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
```

Basically on load i am reading the data from the XML file contains users list and display it into listview. When i click onlist  items it open the user details.Listview also have contextMenu(i.e Delete option) but when i select the context menu item, it throws the class cast exception. I have not much idea about it. please guide me.

Comment: default `ArrayAdapter` uses `TextView` for each element. if u want to use an adapted `View` you'll have to create your own Adapter.

Comment: can u give me some hint about it.

Comment: Which `TextView`s text are you expecting to get by `String userdetail=((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();`?

Comment: actually its textview with id= sendername in user_index_layout

Comment: Try to replace that line with `TextView tv = (TextView)info.targetView.findViewById(R.id.sendername); String userdetail = tv.getText().toString();`